# What drainage slope does artificial grass need?

Tags: slab

what slope should an outside slab have which will have artificial grass glued to it?The slab is joined to a glass covered conservatory

Comment: Can you provide us with more info about your location and situation?

Comment: The slab is within *and* the foundation for a glass conservatory? Or does the glass conservatory have a slightly raised, level foundation wall separate from the pitch of the floor?

Answer (score 1):

Default minimum drainage slope for "flat" surfaces is 1/8" per foot.

*Bring on the short answer complaint robot!*

Comment: Of course a bedding between slab and carpet could change waterflow...

Answer (score 0):

I m a professional grass installer. As per My opinion,In most cases, you should not need a drainage system when buying artificial turf. This is because the artificial turf has its own drainage solution, very effective.

Good quality synthetic turf is designed to be a completely permeable surface, allowing water to flow into the grass. But, it depends on how it is installed.

Most reputable installers will complete a full excavation of the existing surface before installing a fully porous system at the base of the floor. The amount of permeable subbase applied will depend on the quality of your drainage.

By saying this, this installation method can solve most drainage problems. You can read our article on the blog to learn more about why artificial turf is so effective in solving drainage problems in the garden.